# SQL Server: Page Life Expectancy (PLE) sits at zero from 8am until midnight

Tags: sql-server, memory-management

I am struggling to understand SQL Server memory handling in SQL Server 2005

SQL Server is set to take maximum memory of 8GB    PLE is around 3000 at 8am when the users get on the system.   PLE then takes a nose dive to zero and stays at zero until midnight (a bunch of batch jobs are running until then)  It then recovers back to around 3000 for 8am next day

The thing is, I can't see what is causing PLE to drop and stay at zero - it's not even lumpy, it just stays at zero from 8am until midnight !   The "Database pages" stat starts around 200'000 at 8am and slowly degrades to around 70'000.  Other stats look OK,  there are some Lazy writes, but maximum is 6 writes/sec   Checkpoint pages/sec average is 9, Total Server Memory is flat at 1.6GB   Buffer cache dips from 95% to 75% but doesn't go below that

Overall server CPU usage is tiny all day, overall memory usage is flat and the disk usage is tiny, so apart from users complaining about performance and the PLE I would say everything looked ok!

I thought there may be an issue with the PLE stat itself, but all the known issue indicate it would just show as zero all the time, which isn't happening here.

Should I just ignore PLE and not let it distract me from the investigation?

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213010/memory-usage-by-sql-server/213200#213200

Answer (score 0):

very useful script:
https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Scripts/SQLServer_Memory_Information.sql

you see verbose memory utilization:
[image]

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-november-2017/
SQL Server 2005 Diagnostic Information Queries:
see comment 
(Query 27)

```
-- Page Life Expectancy (PLE) value for each NUMA node in current instance  (Query 27) (PLE by NUMA Node)
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name], RTRIM([object_name]) AS [Object Name], instance_name, cntr_value AS [Page Life Expectancy]
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [object_name] LIKE N'%Buffer Node%' -- Handles named instances
AND counter_name = N'Page life expectancy' OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------

-- PLE is a good measurement of memory pressure.
-- Higher PLE is better. Watch the trend over time, not the absolute value.
-- This will only return one row for non-NUMA systems.

-- Page Life Expectancy isn’t what you think…
-- https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/page-life-expectancy-isnt-what-you-think/
```

(28)

```
-- Memory Grants Pending value for current instance (Query 28) (Memory Grants Pending)
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name], RTRIM([object_name]) AS [Object Name], cntr_value AS [Memory Grants Pending]                                                                                                       
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [object_name] LIKE N'%Memory Manager%' -- Handles named instances
AND counter_name = N'Memory Grants Pending' OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------

-- Memory Grants Pending above zero for a sustained period is a very strong indicator of memory pressure
```

(36)

```
-- Cached SP's By Logical Reads (SQL 2005) Logical reads relate to memory pressure  (Query 36) (SP Logical Reads)
SELECT TOP(25) OBJECT_NAME(objectid, dbid) AS [SP Name], qt.[text] AS [SP Text],  
total_logical_reads, qs.max_logical_reads,
total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS [AvgLogicalReads], qs.execution_count AS [Execution Count], 
qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS [Calls/Minute], 
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgWorkerTime],
qs.total_worker_time AS [TotalWorkerTime],
qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgElapsedTime],
qs.total_logical_writes,
 qs.max_logical_writes, qs.total_physical_reads, 
DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS [Age in Cache]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.[sql_handle]) AS qt
WHERE qt.[dbid] = DB_ID() 
ORDER BY total_logical_reads DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------

-- This helps you find the most expensive cached stored procedures from a memory perspective
-- You should look at this if you see signs of memory pressure
```

(37)

```
-- Cached SP's By Physical Reads (SQL 2005) Physical reads relate to read I/O pressure  (Query 37) (SP Physical Reads)
SELECT TOP(25) OBJECT_NAME(objectid, dbid) AS [SP Name], qt.[text] AS [SP Text],  
qs.total_physical_reads, total_logical_reads, qs.max_logical_reads,
total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS [AvgLogicalReads], qs.execution_count AS [Execution Count], 
qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS [Calls/Minute], 
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgWorkerTime],
qs.total_worker_time AS [TotalWorkerTime],
qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgElapsedTime],
DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS [Age in Cache]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.[sql_handle]) AS qt
WHERE qt.[dbid] = DB_ID() -- Filter by current database
AND qs.total_physical_reads > 0
ORDER BY qs.total_physical_reads DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------

-- This helps you find the most expensive cached stored procedures from a read I/O perspective
-- You should look at this if you see signs of I/O pressure or of memory pressure
```

(38)

```
-- Top Cached SPs By Total Logical Writes (SQL 2005)  (Query 38) (SP Logical Writes)
-- Logical writes relate to both memory and disk I/O pressure 
SELECT TOP(25) OBJECT_NAME(objectid, dbid) AS [SP Name], qt.[text] AS [SP Text],  
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.max_logical_writes,
qs.total_logical_writes/qs.execution_count AS [AvgLogicalWrites], qs.execution_count AS [Execution Count], 
qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS [Calls/Minute], 
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgWorkerTime],
qs.total_worker_time AS [TotalWorkerTime],
qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgElapsedTime],
qs.total_physical_reads, 
DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS [Age in Cache]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.[sql_handle]) AS qt
WHERE qt.[dbid] = DB_ID()
AND qs.total_logical_writes > 0 
ORDER BY total_logical_writes DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------

-- This helps you find the most expensive cached stored procedures from a write I/O perspective
-- You should look at this if you see signs of I/O pressure or of memory pressure
```

P.S.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213010/memory-usage-by-sql-server#213200